# How to select the latest records for distinct column values?

Tags: sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

In my database I have profile ids with statuses which also have a timestamp. I want to have the latest status for each profile using a query. How can I do this the easiest way?

So f.e. for:

```
Id      Profile  Timestamp
-------------------------
1        1       1550588089
2        1       1550588099
3        3       1550588183
4        4       1550588333
5        4       1550588534
6        4       1550588377
```

I want to have

```
Id      Timestamp
-------------------------
2       1550588099
3       1550588183
5       1550588534
```

Comment: Which mariadb version?

Comment: Version 10.2.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subquery

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ca0ee1890d8c25689afd33da918b2399)

```
select id as status, Timestamp
from tablename a where timestamp in (select max(timestamp) from tablename b where a.profile=b.profile )
```

OUTPUT:

```
tatus   Timestamps
2       1550588099
3       1550588183
5       1550588534
```

OR you can use `row_number()`

```
select * from 
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by profile order by timestamp desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: Does the first query work? Isn't it right that `Max` just gives one result row?

Comment: @Klyner, have you tried it? it should definitely work

Comment: But you can remove the subquery's GROUP BY.

Comment: @Klyner, you can check here -https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ca0ee1890d8c25689afd33da918b2399

Comment: Thanks a lot for the demo's! It does :)

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()` which support maximum dbms

```
 select * from 
(
 select *,row_number() over(partition by Id order by timestamp desc) rn
 from table
) t where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select profile, max(timestamp) maxtimestamp 
from tablename
group by profile
```

returns all the maximum timestamps for each profile.
So you get what you need by joining it to the main table:

```
select id, timestamp
from tablename t
inner join (
  select profile, max(timestamp) maxtimestamp 
  from tablename
  group by profile 
) g
on g.profile = t.profile and g.maxtimestamp = t.timestamp
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9iemmQZWiKcEvTH9wd8Bzm/0)